# Date Format in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column date in MYSQL, i want to display date in day Month year (day of week) format.

For Example :

if date value is 2011-01-01 than it should display as 1 Jan 2012 (Sun). How should i acheive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d %b %Y (%a )') from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use DATE_FORMAT in mysql:

```
DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%e %b %Y (%a )')
```

`"%m"` will give `numeric` value like `'01','02'` for `Jan`, `Feb` you should use `"%b"`.
and also `"%d"` will return `2 digits like '01','02'` but `"%e" will return '1','2'`.
check out this link for more details, you can change as per your choice.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1):

Refer this MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual for more info

**[Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fdate-format)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

EDITED:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2012-01-01', '%d %b %Y (%a)');` will give you `1 Jan 2012 (Sun)`

```
%d = 01;
%b = Jan;
%Y = 2012;
%a = Sun;
```

For a detailed date formats see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Hope this helps.